# How can i access values from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

How can i access for example `username` and put it in profile page ?

**model/db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const stDB = mongoose.Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('db', stDB);
```

**views/profiles/instructor.hbs**

```
<h5>I want access username from db and put it here!</h5>
```

**index.js**

```
const users = require('../model/db'); // db that username stored in it (model/db.js)

//instructor
router.get('/profiles/instructor', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('./profiles/instructor', { 
    title: 'Instructor'
  });
});

router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next){
    const newUser = new users({
      username : req.body.username,
      email : req.body.email,
      password : req.body.password,
    });
    users.findOne({email : req.body.email}, (err, doc)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log('ERR while getting username =>' + err);
        return ;
      }
      if(doc){
        res.send('this email is already registered before!');
        return ;
      }
      newUser.save((err, doc)=>{
          if(err){
            console.log('err' + err)
          }else{
            console.log(doc)
            res.redirect('/login')
          }
        });
    });
// etc.....
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to use `res.render('template.hbs', { data: doc.email })` to pass the value into your template. Then use `{{ data.email }}`  in the template.. (where `data` is the object you passed to the template)...  [Here is a step by step guide you can follow to get used to handlebars + express](https://medium.com/@waelyasmina/a-guide-into-using-handlebars-with-your-express-js-application-22b944443b65)

Comment: ok i got it in a way, what if i want to console.log() only the current username not all users in database, how can i do that

Comment: It all depends when you want to log this username... `console.log(doc.username)`

Comment: it is not work!